# Increase all controls size and font size

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a dialog in java with some basic controls in it, and I was wondering how could I change the size of all the dialog's controls and font sizes to the double if the parameter BIG_DIALOG was passed as true.

Hope to get some guidelines on how to accomplish this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show the code creating the dialog?

Comment: only in that dialog or the whole of the application? Anyway, it's not supported in core - for ideas, have a look at JGoodies Looks and the FontPolicy/FontSet used internally, not sure if per-window support is available but might be possible to add (never tried, why would you want to have a single dialog stand out of the rest?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your serious about doing this only for the dialog (& not effecting any other components within the GUI), you are going to need to recursively walk the component hierarchy stating at the content pane (you could start higher, but let's makes this easy)

```
protected void changeContent(Container parent) {
    for (Component comp : parent.getComponents()) {
        adjustFont(comp);
        if (comp instanceof Container) {
            changeContent((Container)comp);
        }
    }
}

protected void changeFont(Component comp) {
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(2, 2);
    Font font = comp.getFont().deriveFont(at);
    comp.setFont(font);
}

public MyDialog() {
    changeContent(getConentPane());
}
```

Of course, you should be able to fill the parameter requirements for the constructor & it's logic

**UPDATE**

I put this together and got really awesome results.  I may keep this idea for use in my own code, thanks!

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private float scale = 1f;

    /**
     * Creates new form TestFrame    
     */
public TestFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    btnUp = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnDown = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    jLabel1.setText("Hello world!");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

    jTextField1.setColumns(12);
    jTextField1.setText("Say something");
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    getContentPane().add(jTextField1, gridBagConstraints);

    jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
        String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, gridBagConstraints);

    jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    btnUp.setText("Up");
    btnUp.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnUpActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
    jPanel1.add(btnUp, gridBagConstraints);

    btnDown.setText("Down");
    btnDown.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnDownActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
    jPanel1.add(btnDown, gridBagConstraints);

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
    getContentPane().add(jPanel1, gridBagConstraints);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void btnUpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    
    scale += 0.1;
    changeContent(getContentPane());
    
    invalidate();
    repaint();
    
}

private void btnDownActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    
    scale -= 0.1;
    if(scale <= 0) scale = 0.1f;
    
    changeContent(getContentPane());
    
    invalidate();
    repaint();
    
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new TestFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton btnDown;
private javax.swing.JButton btnUp;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JList jList1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration

protected void changeContent(Container parent) {
    for (Component comp : parent.getComponents()) {
        adjustFont(comp);
        if (comp instanceof Container) {
            changeContent((Container) comp);
        }
    }
}

protected void adjustFont(Component comp) {
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale);
    Font font = comp.getFont();
    System.out.println("Font.orignal = " + font.getSize());
    font = font.deriveFont(at);
    System.out.println("Font.scaled = " + font.getSize());
    comp.setFont(font);
}
}
```

One thing I did note is that the output for the Font.original and Font.scaled is the same.  The transformation is occurring at the paint stage and does not effect the base line font, just it's paint matrix

Comment: weird.... I implemented it... it's going over the components but no size change is happening :(

Comment: Try adding invalidate/repaint after the call? I've not tested the code & will have a look when I get in front of a pc

Comment: solved not because of the invalidate... just added a few tweaks :D

Comment: you're not changing the size of the controllers aren't you? only the font size?

Comment: Nice example. I prefer to replace `invalidate();repaint();` with `pack();` to resize the frame window automatically.

Comment: @oshatrk You could do that, but it will depend on your overall needs

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `"large"` `sizeVariant` like they show [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html).